# Getting id values from a column and then get value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

I have a column value separated by comma as

```
GoalTag:All Tags,TaskTag:All Tags,GoalId:All,TaskId:All,MaxGoal:5,MaxTask:5
```

As you can see I have 6 values separated by comma, so when I do split the first value will be

```
 GoalTag:All Tags
```

How I do this (get the values seperated by comma is) by calling a table valued function

```
Select * from dbo.CustomSplit((SELECT FilterNames FROM TblUserFilterView where UserId = 325 AND Entity = 'Dashboard'),',')
```

The definition for `dbo.CustomSplit` looks like

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CustomSplit](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (Items varchar(8000))     
as     
begin     
    declare @idx int     
    declare @slice varchar(8000)     

    select @idx = 1     
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return     

    while @idx!= 0     
    begin     
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)     
        if @idx!=0     
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
        else     
            set @slice = @String     

        if(len(@slice)>0)
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)     

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
        if len(@String) = 0 break     
    end 
return     
end
```

Now what I need to do is, I need to get the value after the `":"` i.e. "All Tags" it may be some id for some other records let's say it may be "142". I need to get this Id and then get the corresponding value from the table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Substring(s.items, 1 + Charindex ( ':', s.items), 
       Len(s.items) - Charindex (':', 
       s.items)) 
FROM   (SELECT * 
       FROM   dbo.Customsplit((SELECT filternames 
                            FROM   tbluserfilterview 
                            WHERE  userid = 325 
                                   AND entity = 'Dashboard'), ',')) AS s
```

You may create another function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Customsplit2](@string    VARCHAR(8000), 
                                    @Delimiter CHAR(1)) 
returns VARCHAR(4000) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(4000) 
      SELECT @result = Substring(@string, 1 + Charindex ( @Delimiter, @string), 
                                        Len(@string) - Charindex (@Delimiter, 
                                                       @string) 
                       ) 
      RETURN @result 
  END
```

And use it like:

```
SELECT [dbo].Customsplit2(s.items, ':') AS Tag 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   dbo.Customsplit((SELECT filternames 
                                FROM   tbluserfilterview 
                                WHERE  userid = 325 
                                       AND entity = 'Dashboard'), ',')) AS s
```

Comment: yes, it's giving the values correctly, but as a separate records in a row; beside that I need them one by one and get the corresponding value from a table.

Comment: _(...)get the corresponding value from a table_, please edit your question by explaining the next steps in the process after you get those ids.

Comment: Thanks; it's working for me. i'll manage the things for the next step.

Comment: You are welcome! When things get too complicated inside your SQL code, remember that you could write your own CLR function, using any .NET Framework language, including VB.NET and C#. For example, you could use a regular expression pattern to match the searched terms.

Comment: I understand; previously I did that in code behind.. but we have some speed issue so that's why I am trying to get the values from db directly so there will be less db-trips...:)

Comment: SQL CLR functions execute on the SQL server... :)